# How to read the top of a Queue multiple times before dequeueing in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tf-slim

In the following example,  every time I run `sess.run([image, label])`, a different sample from the queue is returned, thus a different `np_image` is returned.

Is there a way that I can let the `slim.queues.QueueRunners` know that I want to use (run) the same sample multiples before a dequeue operation takes place?

The reason I ask is that I have a large op that doesn't fit in my VRAM. I have to break the large op into several small ops and feed a different `feed_dict` every time a small ops is runned. However, when I `run` the small op, `image` changes which break the code. Putting all the small ops in a list and `run` the list at the same time doesn't work for me because the VRAM size is the limitation.

Thanks!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
slim = tf.contrib.slim

from datasets import dataset_utils
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
from datasets import dataset_factory
from deployment import model_deploy
from nets import nets_factory
from preprocessing import preprocessing_factory

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    dataset = dataset_factory.get_dataset('cifar10', 'train','/home/user/dataset/cifar10')

    provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
              dataset,
              num_readers=1,
              common_queue_capacity=256,
              common_queue_min=128)
    [image, label] = provider.get(['image', 'label'])

    image_preprocessing_fn = preprocessing_factory.get_preprocessing(
            'cifarnet',
            is_training=True)

    images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label],
      batch_size=32,
      num_threads=1,
      capacity=64)

    with tf.Session() as sess:    
        with slim.queues.QueueRunners(sess):
            for i in range(3):
                #in every iteration, the tensor 'image' will be different
                #the np_image value will be different as well
                np_image, np_label = sess.run([image, label])
```

Answer (score 1):

Peek operation for queues is currently not supported, for discussion see 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7880

A work-around is to restructure your code to take values from `tf.Variable` objects rather than from `tf.dequeue`. IE something like this

```
x = tf.Variable(queue.dequeue())
y = x+2
sess.run(x.initializer)
sess.run(y) 
sess.run(y)  # same value
sess.run(x.initializer)
sess.run(y)  # new value
```

Comment: Thanks so much Yaroslav.  My guess is that this workaround is only valid if I were interested in the numerical value of the `image` in my example. If that were the case, I can simply store it in a numpy array. When it comes to the gradients `d f(image, theta)/ d theta` where `f` is an arbitrary non-linear function, what is the intuition that this workaround still work?

Comment: Also, can you please let me know what exactly is `x.initializer`? I do not see `initializer` as a method of a Variable(). Do you mean `__init__`?

Comment: running `x.initializer` is equivalent to running `x.assign(initial_value_tensor)`, or `x.assign(queue.dequeue())` op in this case

Comment: it should work for any data, here you are inserting a variable op between your dequeue op and the op that consumes the data